# Issue with columns adjustment after data request

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with serverSide option, and I face a strange behavior. The data refreshed every 5 seconds. If user changes column width, after next data refresh all the columns jump as they were before. I've found a certain place in sources which cause of columns resizing

```
if ( callbackArr ) {
            ret = $.map( settings[callbackArr].slice().reverse(), function (val, i) {
                return val.fn.apply( settings.oInstance, args );
            } );
        }
```

when callbackArr is "aoDrawCallback". I want to disable changing columns width if it has been changed by user. I tried to set autoWidth = false, but in this case table header row become independent of other table and I'm able to change header cells width separately. What is the right way to prevent refreshing column width? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using state option mentioned here? https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

Comment: yes, I have this in table description - "bStateSave" : true

Comment: can you able to provide fiddle/demo to simulate it?